# Start application from ADB

Tags: adb

I have an Android device which I don't have physical access to. But I can access it through ADB commands. I have Teamviewer host installed on it. But unfortunately it's not running. How can I start it using ADB commands? Below is the Teamviwer app that I am using.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.samsung&hl=en

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools

Answer (score 9):

You can launch apps with the `am start` command. Or if you don't know its launcher activity, use the [`monkey`](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey) command.

Try

```
adb shell 

monkey -p your.package.name -v 500
```

where package name is the name of the app package – making the command, in your case:

```
monkey -p com.teamviewer.host.samsung -v 500
```

Comment: `am start -n com.teamviewer.host.samsung/.MainActivity` works fine in most times.

Comment: Yeah if the launcher​ activity is .MainActivity. Otherwise you need monkey

Comment: @iBug +1, A great tip for that `/.MainActivity`. Otherwise it was showing some `Error type 3`  when I was running using adb command

Comment: Setting number of events to one... `monkey -p your.package.name -v 1` ...is also likely to save some unwanted outcomes!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution to access a device could be SCRCPY
https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy

It runs over ADB and mirrors your device on your PC. You can click on all the elements on the devices screen and also type with your PC keyboard.